# Does Math.net Numerics support 4D, 5D or higher dimensional interpolation on irregular grid?

Tags: interpolation, numerics

Does Math.net Numerics support 4D, 5D or higher dimensional interpolation on irregular grid?

My data set is in the format of A, B, C, D, Z. The data set is an irregular grid. I would like to interpolate to get Z given A, B, C, D.

If yes, what is the way to do it in Math.net Numerics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up after much research

No, Math.Net Numerics doesn't support 4D, 5D or higher dimensional interpolation on irregular grid.

I ended up using [Scipy RBF](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) which was verified running 4D interpolation. I didn't have the chance to verify 5D or higher dimension.

This [Scipy RBF Tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/RadialBasisFunctions) is very useful to setup a quick working prototype.

Comment: If you found the answer please don't forget to accept it as the the good answer to your question.